# SQL select all distinct rows from first column with random values from other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

I have something like this:

```
id      email       email2      id_2
------------------------------------------
1       James@      james2@        11          
1       James@      james2@        11          
1       James@         -           11  
1       James@         -           11  
2       Declan@     dylan2@        22          
2       Declan@     dylan2@        44        
3       John@          -           33
3       John@          -           33         
4       Vito@       vito2@         55
```

so I need to select all values for distinct id, if email2 is not empty i should choose one with not empty email2, but if there are only empty email2, choose  one. For example:

```
id      email       email2      id_2
------------------------------------------
1       James@      james2@        11               
2       Declan@     dylan2@        22          
3       John@          -           33         
4       Vito@       vito2@         55
```

There isn't any more conditions so I don't know what to do. Usually I use partiotion by or group by.. Please , help me.

Comment: What should happened when a user has multiple email2 values?

Answer (score 1):

Given your sample data, using the `max` or `min` aggregate should get you your desired results:

```
select id, max(email), max(email2), min(id_2)
from yourtable 
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case when email2 is not null then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This method allows you to pull any columns you want from a row with both emails.

Note:  This assumes that `-` actually means `NULL`.  The `case` would need to be modified if the actual value is a hyphen.